# Removing a Recently Used Query from the List on the Work Items Tab of Pending Changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

On the Work Items tab of the Pending Changes window in Visual Studio (I'm using 2008), there is a dropdown list for the Query field which contains recently selected queries. Where is this list stored? I'd like to clean the list up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's one for each server you've connected to: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache\WorkItemHistory_[guid].config

where [guid] is the server's GUID.

Comment: I know you'd find it - but for VS2010 it's at %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache